# R: Apply rpart regression tree result to other data

Tags: r, tree, rpart

After applying an Rpart() function to a dataset in R, from using:

```
print(R_Part_Train_Output)
```

I have ended up with these results:

```
 1) root 3678351 1121767000 30.46863  
   2) Var1>=4.5 2889077  732026500 26.62383  
     4) Var2=E Europe,Eur Union,Irish Rep,Oth 1097632  163740000 19.31832  
       8) Var3< 133.5 495297   30775570 16.70123 *
       9) Var3>=133.5 602335  126782600 21.47033 *  
     5) Var2=Africa,Aus NZ,Car, L Am,E Asia,M East C Asia,N America,S Asia 1791445  473812200 31.09997  
       10) Var3< 180.5 1042740  128509300 27.32818  
         20) Var3 < 110.5 410147   27371200 24.29461 *   
         21) Var3>=110.5 632593   94916560 29.29503 *  
       11) Var3>=180.5 748705  309808200 36.35303  
         22) Var4=B 99523   20792900 29.26750 *  
         23) Var4=A 649182  283252800 37.43929 *  
   3) Var1< 4.5 789274  190704300 44.54223  
     6) Var3< 168.5 374571   50560270 40.89094 *  
     7) Var3>=168.5 414703  130639800 47.84017 *
```

Is there a way to apply this regression tree splitting to datasets other than those used to create the tree itself. 
I could of course split this data manually into these sections however this would be cumbersome with both constructing the code and applying it due to the large number of observations. An in-built function would be much simpler.

Comment: Look at `?predict.rpart`

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can use predict.  See ?predict.rpart

```
library(rpart)
TreeModel = rpart(Petal.Width ~ ., iris[,1:4])
TreeModel
n= 150 
node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node
 1) root 150 86.5699300 1.199333  
   2) Petal.Length< 2.45 50  0.5442000 0.246000 *
   3) Petal.Length>=2.45 100 17.8624000 1.676000  
     6) Petal.Length< 4.75 45  1.5200000 1.300000 *
     7) Petal.Length>=4.75 55  4.7752730 1.983636  
      14) Petal.Length< 5.05 13  0.4676923 1.730769 *
      15) Petal.Length>=5.05 42  3.2190480 2.061905 *

NewPoint = data.frame(Sepal.Length = 4.5, Sepal.Width=3.3, Petal.Length=0.2)
predict(TreeModel, NewPoint)
    1 
0.246
```